# Flask redirect entering route twice

Tags: python, redirect, post, flask

I would like to be able to pass messages from a `POST` redirect to other templates. See the edit for the specific blueprint structure and routes / views.

After `POST`ing to the `_update_test` route, it prints `>> about to redirect`

Then, I can see with my debugger that the `browse_tests` route is entered and the message content is as expected (what was provided from Flask's `redirect()` function. I see `>> about to render template` is printed to the console

Problem is, before the page `base_browse_test.html` is rendered, the `browse_tests` route is entered a second time and the `message` component is gone from the request, so the template renders with an empty message (`message = ''`). I see `>> about to render template` is printed a second time before the page renders.

What am I missing here?

**EDIT**: here is the blueprint structure

`root/webapp/__init__.py`: (the entirety of this file can be found [at this pastebin](http://pastebin.com/qdH8iGVz))

```
def create_app('development'):
    webapp = Flask(__name__)
    ...
    from .mod_tests import tests as tests_blueprint
    webapp.register_blueprint(tests_blueprint, url_prefix='/tests')
    return webapp
```

`root/webapp/mod_tests/__init__.py`:

```
from flask import Blueprint
tests = Blueprint('tests', __name__)
from . import manage_tests_views
```

`root/webapp/mod_tests/manage_tests_views.py`:

```
@tests.route('/_update_test', methods=['POST'])
    def update_test():
        ...
        print 'about to redirect'
        return redirect(url_for('tests.browse_tests', message={"main":"foo message content"}))


@tests.route('/browse_tests', methods=['GET'])
@login_required
def browse_tests():
    if request.args.get('message'):
        message = request.args['message']
    else:
        message = ''
    print 'about to render template'
    return render_template('tests/base_browse_tests.html',
                           message=message)
```

- Running with or without the debugger makes no difference.
- `request.accept_mimetypes` is equal to a `MIMEAccept dict` containing `('*/*', 1)` on the first request (message intact, query string included in request) and contains `('text/html', 1), ('image/webp', 1), ('application/xhtml+xml', 1), ('application/xml', 0.9), ('*/*', 0.8)` on the second, empty query string request. Is this any kind of clue?
- the `request.cookies['session']` string value does not change, although the dubugger seems to think it does (by turning it blue in my IDE)
- `request.fullpath` is equal to `u'/tests/browse_tests?notification=<encoded json>'` on the first, notification-intact request. `request.fullpath` equals `u'/tests/browse_tests?'` on the second, notification-absent request
- `request.is_xhr` == `True` on the first, notification-intact request. It is `False` on the second, notification-absent request
- `request.environ['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] = 'XMLHttpRequest'` first, and it is absent on the second request.
- `request.environ['HTTP_UPGRADE_INSECURE_REQUESTS'] is absent from the first request, and equals`'1'` on the second request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry everyone, there was an errant redirect left in the javascript that executes on that page. Let this serve as a reminder to be careful.

This question may be closed as the solution was not at all related to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There must be something wrong with your Blueprint structure or it usage

I tried reproducing your code on my machine without blueprint and it worked !

In your code  modify this line and run, it may work.
I made the POST request using [this](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop?hl=en)

```
return redirect(url_for('tests.browse_tests', message={"main":"foo message content"}))
```

## TO

```
return redirect(url_for('.browse_tests', message={"main":"foo message content"}))
```

This is what i did on my machine

Test/

----hello.py

----templates/

--------base_browse_tests.html

## hello.py

```
from flask import Flask, redirect, url_for, request, render_template
from flask.ext.login import login_required
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello World!"


@app.route('/_update_test', methods=['POST'])
def update_test():

    print '>>>>>>>>>>>>>>about to redirect'
    message={"main":"foo message content"}
    return redirect(url_for('browse_tests', message=message ))


@app.route('/browse_tests', methods=['GET'])
def browse_tests():

    if request.args.get('message'):
    message = request.args['message']
    else:
    message = ''

    print '##################about to render template'

    return render_template('base_browse_tests.html',
                       message=message)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

## base_browse_tests.html

```
<h1>Message: {{message}}</h1>
```

peace

Comment: thanks for the assistance, but it was me being careless that caused this one. I left an errant javascript reroute hidden in a script.